# Select :target element on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to select the `:target` element on page load using jQuery using the following code, but it isn't finding anything and is returning `[]`. Why isn't it working?

```
$(function () {
    var $target = $(':target');
    console.log($target); // []

    if ($target.length) {
        $target.addClass('kbactive');
    }
});
```

Running `$(':target')` manually after page load works fine; why doesn't it work immediately?

Comment: Are you using some kind of plugin?

Comment: No, I am not using a plugin

Comment: Seems like `:target` pseudo selector is not supported: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation. Could you write what element exactly you're trying to get?

Comment: > There is definitely a target element, and running $(':target') manually in the console returns the correct element.

Comment: I've never heard of a :target selector. I tried a couple google searches as well and nothing is returned.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:target

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified; I never heard of a jQuery/Sizzle :target selector. I'm familiar with the CSS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems :target isn't parsed until the document has loaded completely. If you run your code on load instead of on ready it works. Maybe you could ask the browser dev team or check the source code why that's the case.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
location.hash
```

to get your target id, so to get the element you can simply do

```
document.getElementById(location.hash);
```

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to get. I'm trying to get the linked element (that's what `:target` is)

Comment: Yeah, it's that. `location.hash` returns the hash, not the element.

Comment: Updated answer... is that not what you want to do?

Comment: var target =  location.hash; $('#'+target)

Comment: How is that hacky? You have an ID in your url and you are getting the corresponding element...

Comment: @CallumMacrae: No it's not hacky. It follows the specs (as far as what the `:target` element should be) and it works. If you don't want to do that, your `$(':target')` call will have to be in the `onLoaded` event versus `onDOMReady`. **The fact of the matter is `:target` is not officially supported by jQuery**. While it my works with some browsers that properly returns it when using `querySelectorAll()`, it will [**definitely not work in IE8 or lower**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3). The only cross-browser solution is this one.

Comment: @CallumMacrae - And you do understand that jQuery decomposes into pure JS (which is what this is)...

Comment: Note that: "In old-style HTML <a name="foo"> is a target element.  The :target pseudo-class applies to those targets as well." Using `location.hash` is trickier, but certainly doable, for that.

Answer (score 1):

If by `:target` you mean:

> The :target pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with
>   an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document.

You can try:

```
$(window.location.hash)
```

The reason why `$(':target')` might not work properly is because it’s not documented in the jQuery API and it’ not clear if the selector’s engine can run it.

Anyway, accessing `window.location.hash` and use it as a selector is *exactly* the same.

Comment: That's hacky, so no, I don't want to do that.

Comment: @CallumMacrae So, the problem is that you want to use an undocumented jQuery selector instead of native properties? Ok then, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The **`:target`** pseudo-selector is not officially supported by jQuery. While it might work in browsers that **both support the [CSS3 `:target` pseudo-class](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget) and [`querySelectorAll()`](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll), it will not work in browsers that do not (IE8+).**

The clean, cross browser way of selecting the same element on DOM Ready is do use `location.hash`:

```
if(location.hash) {
    var target = $(location.hash); // location.hash already includes the #
}
```

That said, if you do not like that because *"it's hacky"* (it is absolutely not), you can add support for the `:target` selector yourself in jQuery:

```
$.expr[":"].target = $.expr.createPseudo(function(s)
{
    return function(el)
    {
        if(location.hash)
            return $(el).attr('id') == location.hash.substring(1);

        return false;
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have changed your code to use LeviBotelho's suggestion

```
$(function () {
    var targetID = window.location.hash;
    var $target = $( targetID );
    console.log($target);

    if ($target.length) {
        $target.addClass('kbactive');
    }
});
```

For more information on the `:target` selector and browser compatibility check out the MDN site [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3atarget)

Although the above will work I do have some warnings.

As Callum Macrae mentioned the above is a little hacky. [The HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) states

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Technically speaking you can use colons in an ID and if the colon is escaped in location.hash to `%3A` then the above solution might not work.

In HTML 5 many of these restrictions have been lifted and this issue is even more likely. More info [**here**](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class)

Comment: LeviBotelho came up with that six minutes ago, please read my comments on his answer.

Comment: @LeviBotelho Improved answer.